# Call EJB 3.1 from EJB 2 client

Tags: web-services, client, websphere, ejb-3.1

I need to develop a server side component to accomplish some internal task for my company.

We have a Java EE scheduler application deployed on WebSphere 6.x that will be my client application.

I'd like to write my server side component with EJB 3.1 or with another Java EE 6 compliant technology.

Can I generate a legacy EJB 2.1 client for my component with maven?

Is it better to use another solution like web services and let the scheduler generate his own client?

Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Web Services. EJB will involved RMI/IIOP and serialization. Since you will have 2 different servers, JDK versions you may have much more troubles using EJB integration. If communication is asynchronous, you could also consider JMS.